# What is the value of the following expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Evaluate:
$$\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{8}\right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{100}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{8}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{1}{100}\right)}$$

I have never come across this before and was wondering if someone would show me how they would work this out? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried evaluating each individual expression and seeing if anything cancels out? That's a good first step.

Answer (score 6):

We can Write it as $\displaystyle \prod_{r=1}^{50}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2r}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2r}\right)} = \prod_{r=1}^{50}\frac{2r+1}{2r-1}$

After expanding we get $\displaystyle = \frac{3}{1}\cdot \frac{5}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{5}\cdot \frac{9}{7}......\frac{99}{97}.\frac{101}{99} = 101$

Answer (score 5):

$$= \frac{\frac32 \frac54\frac76\cdots\frac{101}{100}}{\frac12\frac34\frac56\cdots\frac{99}{100}}=101$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying top and bottom by $$2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 8\cdots 100$$ the expression becomes
$$\frac{\qquad \;3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 9\cdots \;\;\;99\cdot 101}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdots \;97\cdot 99\quad }=\color{red}{101}$$